# One table with 2 foreign key mapping same primary key

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
  status,
  schedule_switch.Switch_Employee_ID,
  schedule_switch.Requesting_Employee_ID,
  employee_info.FirstName,
  DATE_FORMAT(schedule_switch.date, '%m-%d-%Y') AS switchdate,
  DATE_FORMAT(time_slot.date, '%m-%d-%Y') AS date,
  start_time,end_time
FROM
  work_schedule
    join time_slot on work_schedule.Slot_ID = time_slot.Slot_ID
    join manager_info on manager_info.Manager_ID = time_slot.Manager_ID
    join schedule_switch on work_schedule.Schedule_ID = schedule_switch.Schedule_ID
    join employee_info on schedule_switch.switch_Employee_ID = employee_info.Employee_ID
    join employee_info on schedule_switch.requesting_Employee_ID = employee_info.Employee_ID
where
  status is null
order by
  switchdate;
```

I am stuck with this query. I need to get the first name of `switch_employee_id` and `requesting_employee_id` both connected to one primary key `Employee_ID` in the `employee_info` table.

Comment: I don't know mysql but in mssql would use a table alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    status,
    schedule_switch.Switch_Employee_ID,
    schedule_switch.Requesting_Employee_ID,
    empl_info1.FirstName,
    empl_info2.FirstName, //added the modified join select column
    DATE_FORMAT(schedule_switch.date, '%m-%d-%Y') AS switchdate,
    DATE_FORMAT(time_slot.date, '%m-%d-%Y') AS date,
    start_time,
    end_time
FROM work_schedule
    JOIN time_slot ON work_schedule.Slot_ID = time_slot.Slot_ID
    JOIN manager_info ON manager_info.Manager_ID = time_slot.Manager_ID
    JOIN schedule_switch ON work_schedule.Schedule_ID = schedule_switch.Schedule_ID
    JOIN employee_info empl_info1 ON schedule_switch.switch_Employee_ID = empl_info1.Employee_ID
    // modified your join
    JOIN employee_info empl_info2 ON schedule_switch.requesting_Employee_ID = empl_info2.Employee_ID
WHERE status IS NULL
ORDER BY switchdate;
```

Comment: so it is just the ambiguity between names that was creating the error ?. thanks a lot man ...

Comment: Yes you joined the employee_info table  twice with the same name. This causes the error by giving both joins an alias the error is solved